# order by a some part of the string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have these value in generated_code column

```
NEW 6y0m
!EW 0y8m
N!W 5y11m
!EW 17y0m
```

I would like to order it ascending based on the year which is located after the space and before the 'y'. outcome should be something like this

```
!EW 17y0m
NEW 6y0m
N!W 5y11m
!EW 0y8m
```

i tried this, but it returns empty set

```
select
   mid(generated_code,4,LOCATE(generated_code,'y')-6) 
from
   classifier_bahrain 
order by
   mid(generated_code,4,LOCATE(generated_code,'y')-6) desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters for `locate` function should be in reverse order. Also if you try to order by the substring, it will be in the order 6,5,17,0. 
So convert it to int before ordering the result.

Try this:

```
SELECT generated_code,SUBSTR(generated_code,4,locate('y',generated_code)-4) as ORDERBY
FROM classifier_bahrain 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(generated_code,4,locate('y',generated_code)-4) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Result:

```
GENERATED_CODE  ORDERBY
!EW 17y0m       17
NEW 6y0m        6
N!W 5y11m       5
!EW 0y8m        0
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2318/10)